# Azure Machine Learning in dynamics

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I just started to work with Azure Machine Learning using Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio.

Could you please advise the proper way of using Classification Model so that the Model can analyze the window/interval with series of information before it reaches the target/class which should be predicted further on by Model?

Our problem could be solved only by analyzing all the previous information in it's dynamic/evolution (e.g. depending on the dynamical change of the Patient's medical results it could be found out some sickness including it's current stage and the stage which we could expect in medium term).

For example in an input file we do not provide in each row together with the variables the target info, it is shown only at the row/moment when the situation is matured to reach such target.

If it is already available some materials/tutorials on this subject in Azure ML or somewhere else I would highly appreciate such info and links.

Thanks in advance for your kind support!

Best regards,
Berik

Answer (score 0):

Viewing health failure as a "predictive maintenance" problem for the human body, I suggest you check out our materials on predictive maintenance in aerospace:

- Notebooks for [R](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Notebook/Predictive-Maintenance-Modelling-Guide-R-Notebook-1) and [Python](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Notebook/Predictive-Maintenance-Modelling-Guide-Python-Notebook-1), and [associated Azure ML experiment](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Predictive-Maintenance-Modelling-Guide-Experiment-1)
- [Predictive Maintenance for Aerospace solution](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Solution/Predictive-Maintenance-for-Aerospace-4)

You can use a similar approach to generate new features such as "disease will reach critical stage in X months", "number of ER visits in past year," etc. that can be calculated for any timepoint, so that you can convert from your time series data to a low-missingness dataframe.

You'll notice that for the most part, these examples don't use built-in Azure ML functions to create their rolling window features. Since they were written, a few custom modules like [Generate Lag Features](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/CustomModule/Generate-Lag-Features-1) have been released; maybe some of these will be useful to you.

That being said, the prediction problem you describe is complex and I don't know what accuracy you can reasonably hope to achieve. For help choosing evaluation metrics, check out this [Predictive Maintenance Data Science Playbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/cortana-analytics-playbook-predictive-maintenance). Watch out for common pitfalls, e.g. a "model" that invariably predicts a rare event will not occur can have very high accuracy.